# Enable backing store feature in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, configuration

Can you tell me how to enable the 'backing store' feature in Ubuntu 12.04?

I tried adding `xserver-command=X +bs` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. With this configuration setting xserver fails to start correctly. I get a frozen window with a message saying resolution is set to a small value (I think it was 800x480, but I can't recall).

Comment: Are using 12.04 desktop or Server.

Comment: 12.04 is EOL. OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years to check comments on this unanswered question. VTC as `not reproducible`.